# Entity Framework doesn't work in VS2015 (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

When I run my old projects written using Entity Framework v6.1.3 they don't work. I tried to run them through Visual Studio - nothing.. I understand the problem in working with databases. When I compile the project I see the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)

Comment: @Rhys I don't have file/folder/ect with name MS SQL SERVER but in Control Panel->Microsoft SQL Server 2014 exits

Comment: What kind of SQL Server are you using LocalDb or a real, full, SQL Server installation?  Also, post your connection string.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I use a local server. And as I see it is set for me. I installed VS 2015, as I understand it comes?
and my con. string:
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=userstore.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>

Comment: problem solved. it was necessary to install Local DB 2012